# not work grid(view) in c#(wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

Table is created, but rows are empty, why?

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("...");
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select id,id_user,status,id_delivery_method,delivery_method,id_payment_method,payment_method,payment_info,user_name,user_phone from `request`", conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Comment: Are you sure there is any data in the table? Have you run it in debug to see what information the cmd returns?

Comment: I had an equal problem and worked arround it by setting `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false`

Comment: How is your datagrid defined in XML?

Comment: webber2k6, thanks!!! works :)

Comment: @webber2k6 - Please post your comment as answer so that it can be accepted as an answer and help others.

Comment: sorry, it was only a guess so i've not written it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `AutoGenerateColums = false` and define the columns by yourself:

in XAML:

```
<DataGrid ... AutoGenerateColums="false">
    <DataGrid.Columns><!-- Your columns --></DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

in Code-behind:

```
yourDatagrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```